# When did my computer went to sleep the last time? Window 7

Tags: windows, windows-7

I wanted a windows service I'm building to run overnight. So I changed my power options and set my computer to never sleep. Started the windows service and went home. This morning I found my computer sleeping and was curious if someone manually put it to sleep after I left. Is there a log file or some way to find the last time my computer went to sleep? I'm using a Windows 7 operating system.

Comment: Are you just trying to figure out what happened last night, or make something to run today and in the future that logs it?

Comment: Just trying to figure out what happened last night.

Comment: filter event ID 42 in System in Event viewer. ref: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/logging-power-events-sleep-wake-up-to-the-event/e004a68c-f9a9-4982-86ba-a1cee05f9e4d

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you consulted Event Viewer? To start [Event Viewer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766401.aspx) by using a command line

- Open a command prompt. To open a command prompt, click Start, click All Programs, click Accessories and then click Command Prompt.
- Type **eventvwr**.

Information about scheduled / unscheduled sleeps and reboots should be found by expanding the tree view in the left plan to Event Viewer > Windows Logs > System.

You can also get the last boot time by using the WMI service object to query the LastBootUpTime property of the Win32_OperatingSystem class. Note that the returned date is in WMI date time format which you'll need to use tools to convert into a human readable date.

Here's a VBScript sample:

```vb
' LastBoot.vbs
Option Explicit
Dim wmiService, objDateTime, OS
Set wmiService = GetObject("winmgmts://localhost/root/cimv2")
Set objDateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
Set OS = wmiService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem").ItemIndex(0)
WScript.Echo OS.LastBootUpTime ' Example: 20180801131622.495364+660
objDateTime.Value = OS.LastBootUpTime
WScript.Echo objDateTime.GetVarDate ' Example: 01/08/2018 12:16:22 PM
```

Here's a PowerShell example:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime
# Outputs: 20181009160558.495300+660

(gcim Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime
# Outputs: Wednesday, 1 August 2018 12:16:22 PM
```

Here's a Command Prompt example (uses PowerShell):

```
powershell -command "(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime"
REM Outputs: 20180801131622.495364+660

powershell -command "(gcim Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime"
REM Outputs: Wednesday, 1 August 2018 12:16:22 PM
```

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem
- http://powershell-guru.com/powershell-tip-7-convert-wmi-date-to-datetime/
- https://www.thewindowsclub.com/find-system-uptime-windows

Answer (score 5):

Inside eventvwr you will see the entry in System Logs --> "Kernel Power". Double click to see when your computer entered into sleep mode.

Comment: Simple and just what I needed. Thank you.